# Run .desktop file with its own icon in Icons Task Manager KDE Plasma Wayland

Tags: kde, wayland, plasma, icons, .desktop

I have the following configuration:

Debian Trixie; Wayland; KDE 5.107.0 / Plasma 5.27.10

I have two `.desktop` files to launch two instances of brave browser with two different profiles and two different icons

Profile #1 (brave standard `.destkop` file)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser --profile-directory=Default %u
Icon=brave-browser
MimeType=text/html;image/webp;image/png;image/jpeg;image/gif;application/xml;application/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;application/pdf;
Name[en_US]=Brave Web Browser
Name=Brave Web Browser
NoDisplay=false
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Profile #2

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser '--profile-directory=Profile 7' %u
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/download.png
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=Brave Web Browser Pippo
Name=Brave Web Browser Pippo
NoDisplay=false
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

When I launch Krunner I see the two different icons, but when I run the two brave instances, I get the two standard brave icons in the icons task manager.

I also tried to add `StartupWMClass=brave-browser` in Profile #2 `.desktop` file and it seems to set the correct icon, but it I run a brave instance with Profile #1 it gets the same icon as the one of Profile #2

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

> when I run the two brave instances, I get the two standard brave icons
> in the icons task manager.

I'm afraid that this is normal (and not tuneable) behavior in kde-plasma.
It is at least what I can experiment and cannot change under my 5.25.5.

This is because the icons shown in the tasks manager applet (or alternatives) are **not** related to the image file as defined on the *Icon* line of the desktop file [but to the icons reported by the applications themselves.](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tasks) :

> Whenever you start an application you will see a new tab in the Task
> Manager showing **the icon of the application**

Ergo : Two occurrences of the same application running => Two identical icons in the task manager applets, irrespective of whatever .desktop setting.